# Vector perpendicular to three vectors

Tags: linear-transformations

```
                           u = i+2j+3k
                           v = -i+2j+k
                           w = 3i+j
```

find the value of p such that (u+pv) is perpendicular to w

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

If two **non-zero** vectors $\vec{a} \text{ and } \vec{b} $ are perpendicular and then,

$$\vec{a} \cdot\vec{b} = 0 \iff \vec{a} \perp \vec{b} \text{ as } |a|, |b| \ne 0$$

Comment: Did you not know what "perpendicular" meant or did you just not want to do the arithmetic?  With the given u and v, u+ pv= (1- p)i+ (2+ 2p)j+ (3+ p)k.  Its dot product with w is 3(1- p)+ (2+ 2p)= 5- p and, to be perpendicular, that dot product must equal 0.

Comment: I was hoping that vishai would do that him or herself!

Answer (score 0):

From $(u+pv)\cdot w=0$ and $v\cdot w\neq0$ give$$p=-\frac{u\cdot w}{v\cdot w}$$
a try.